# 100% elements with sticky footer

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I'm working with bootstrap V3. I've seen working code that provides a solution to the sticky footer problem but this then stops me from having any div elements with 100% height in the body which I need.

Does anyone know of any solutions to this issue without using any javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: table` to your parent element (like the body) and then on your footer, add

```
display:        table-row; 
vertical-align: bottom; 
height:         1px;
```

The height isn't going to make the footer only `1px` tall, so don't worry about that.

That's what I usually do, always works for me when using bootstrap.

Comment: <html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body style="display:table;">
<div>
This is some content
</div>
<div id="footer" style="display:table-row; vertical-align: bottom; height:1px;">
This should be a sticky footer
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Try adding a containing div right after your body, and give it the styles: `position: absolute`, `min-width: 100%`, `min-height: 100%`, `overflow: hidden`. That's typically what I do, and I haven't really found any glaring problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul - I modified your code and added 100% height to the body element which now works ok.

```
    <html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body style="display:table;height:100%;">
<div style="height:100%;background-color:red;">
This is some content
</div>
<div id="footer" style="display:table-row; vertical-align: bottom; height:1px;">
This should be a sticky footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```